# Zend_Session_Namespace and setExpirationSeconds

Tags: zend-framework, zend-session

I have problem for set a timeout on Zend_Auth Session this is my code :

```
$authSession = new Zend_Session_Namespace('Zend_Auth');
$authSession->setExpirationSeconds(60*60*24*1);
```

This code should make session expire after 1 day but actualy session expire after about 30 min. Anyone know what's wrong ? Thank you.

Comment: may be you are not allowed to change the session timeout?

Comment: are you using one of the remote adapters like OpenId where the server may be expiring you?

Comment: this might help you: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489807/zend-framework-session-expires-prematurely>.

Comment: why are you using namespace Zend_Auth which is reserved for zf ? try with any other name not starting with Zend instead.

Answer (score 7):

The default [session.gc_maxlifetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) value in `php.ini` which specifies the number of seconds after which session data will be seen as 'garbage' is 24 minutes.

Calling `Zend_Session_Namespace::setExpirationSeconds()` is an internal to Zend Framework and has no effect on the session cookie itself or the session data on the server.

Make sure to adjust your `session.gc_maxlifetime` value accordingly such that PHP won't delete the data before you want it to.  You can set this directly in `php.ini` or you can use `ini_set` somewhere in your bootstrap, or from your ZF `application.ini` file, use something like `resources.session.gc_maxlifetime = 864000`

See also:
Paragraph 2 of [persisted login with Zend_Session::rememberMe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537305/persisted-login-with-zend-sessionrememberme/9539452#9539452)
[How do I create persistent sessions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797913/how-do-i-create-persistent-sessions-in-php/9797962#9797962)
Paragraph 4 of [Zend Framework Automatic Logout after inactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344577/zend-framework-automatic-logout-after-inactivity/9347745#9347745)

Comment: 864000 = 10 days. for 1 day, use 86400